# Adjust Y axis only for Octoprint Bed Visualizer

Tags: octoprint, y-axis

I am using the Octoprint Bed Visualizer on my Ender 3/BLTouch setup.  When it moves to the front left corner, the BLTouch sensor nearly misses the bed touching the very edge.  Likewise, it is shifted fairly far forward in the back.

Is it possible to shift the Y axis only for the visualizer?  I see there is an [M206 gcode](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M206.html) that apparently does this, but putting the code into the Visualizer settings doesn't seem to make a difference.

**UPDATE**: I checked the firmware settings and they are set as follows, which seem correct,

```
X_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER -41
Y_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER -5
X_BED_SIZE 235
Y_BED_SIZE 235
```

Comment: did you define the offset of the Z-probe to the nozzle position in the firmware?

Comment: Yes when I updated the firmware I believe I set it correctly but I’ll double check.  Thanks for the reminder

Comment: I found a good external link that I'm going to play with for a bit: https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/wiki/How-to-center-your-prints-on-the-bed

Comment: Did you set the correct boundaries for the sensor in your firmware? You might want to read: ["How to set Z-probe boundary limits in firmware when using automatic bed leveling?"](/q/8153).

Comment: Ah thanks. It looks like I may be able to make use of MIN_PROBE_EDGE.  I’ll flash some new settings and give it a try.

Comment: A minimum probe value added to the boundaries is part of the problem, identifying the correct bed limits for the probe is the first hurdle to take.

Comment: I have no MIN_PROBE_VALUE currently added to the boundaries.  Since I'm having issues with the sizing I could either adjust the size of the bed or tweak it through the *_PROBE_BED_POSITION values.

Comment: Have you made any progress to answer your own question? Or did the question ["How to set Z-probe boundary limits in firmware when using automatic bed leveling?"](/q/8153) help you to fix the problem?

Comment: Ultimately I simply adjusted the PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER values to shift the probe touch position in the direction that I wanted.  This effectively moved the entire working area on the bed in the direction I needed.  It's a bit of a hack but it worked for my purposes.

Comment: Could you post your last comment as an answer, please..? If you answer in the comments then the Q&A mechanism of the site gets broken, and in addition, it doesn't decrease the length of our unanswered queue, which we need to keep to a minimum in order to graduate out of being a beta site. Many thanks. :-)